# javascript reference in xslt

Tags: javascript, xslt

I have a javascript file.

how can i reference that file from within XSLT.

Comment: More details would help here.

Comment: You want to use javascript in xslt?  Why?  That's like asking how you can use C in a javascript file.

Comment: Are you talking about xslt extension mechanisms? Or you simple want to create HTML using XSLT and want to embed/reference JavaScript in your output document?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourfile.js"></script>
```

however if you are finding that it is self closing you need to add a space in like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourfile.js">&#160;</script>
```

Comment: I wonder the reason behind adding space here. Though browser fails understand the next script blocks if space is not added.

Comment: without the space the xslt automatically self closes the tag which then causes problems.